# Use .htaccess to redirect to a symlinked subdir of the web root?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, symlink

I'm trying to use Envoyer.io to deploy my code and I'm running into some issues.

This utility makes two folders, `current` and `releases`. `current` symlinks to latest release in the `releases` folder.

So my directory structure looks like this:

- public_html

  - current - symlinked to releases/{release_id}
  - releases

    - {release_id}

      - public
      - (other contents)

I need all requests to go to the `current/public` directory, making this the webroot, as opposed to `public_html`.

I have tried the obvious option of setting my webroot to `public_html/current/public`, but I am then faced with the error: `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /home/mysite/public_html/current`

I have attempted variations of `Options +FollowSymLinks` in my `.htaccess` file with no luck here. I believe I am unable to access the Apache conf files, since this is a shared host.

I would appreciate any guidance on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help repeating myself:

Most people who use `.htaccess` and ask about it on ServerFault should not be using `.htaccess` in the first place as that is an end-user solution never intended [for administrators](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic):

> You should **avoid using `.htaccess` files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.
>   More in the [Apache **manual**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

To be able to use the [`FollowSymlinks`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) directive in a `.htaccess` file the main server config needs to allow that by either setting `AllowOverride All`  or when a slightly less generous setting is used the option needs to be explicitly enabled with with an [`AllowOverride Option=FollowSymlinks`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive as it is not part of the default groupings of `AuthConfig`, `FileInfo`, `Indexes` or `Limit`.